# Trouble w/ bash programmable completion of filenames matching patterns

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I've got a simple command named `th`. I've got a bash-completion file for it that goes as follows:

```
_th()  {
  COMPREPLY=()
  local curr=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
  COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -f -X '!*.@(tar|tar.xz|tar.bz2|tar.gz|tbz|tgz)' -- "$curr") )
}                
complete -F _th -o filenames th
```

This works as intended, for the most part. For arguments to my `th` function, BASH only tab-completes files ending in `.tar`, .`tar.xz`, etc. Two problems:

1. The matching is case-sensitive. Not all tar files have lower-case extensions. (Using `shopt` to set `nocaseglob` inside the bash-completion file doesn't work.)
2. The matching chokes on multi-word filenames, e.g. files with spaces in their names.

   ```
   [rsaw:blahb]$ ls
   bam.tgz  boom.TGZ  sad.TAR  spaces in this-file.tbz
   [rsaw:blahb]$ th<tabtab>
   bam.tgz        in             spaces         this-file.tbz  
   [rsaw:blahb]$ th spa<tabtab>
   in             spaces         this-file.tbz  
   [rsaw:blahb]$ th spaces<tabtab>   # At this point I added a backslash and pressed tab until 4 backslashes appeared
   in             spaces         this-file.tbz  
   [rsaw:blahb]$ th spaces\\\\<tabtab>   # At this point, nothing else happened
   ```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still an issue for you but I ran into something similar while trying to get mid-word filename completion and have some ideas for possible solutions.

Changing the `IFS` variable by adding `local IFS=$'\n'` fixed the problem with spaces in filenames for me, might be worth a try.

As for making things case-insensitive, you could force `$curr` to lowercase for compgen by using `${cur,,}`. Full function would look like this after both changes:

```
_th()  {
  local IFS=$'\n'
  local curr=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
  COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -f -X '!*.@(tar|tar.xz|tar.bz2|tar.gz|tbz|tgz)' -- "${curr,,}") )
}                
complete -F _th -o filenames th
```

That would make the whole filename matching case-insensitive. If you only want the extension case insensitive you could do some string manipulation to `$cur` to make only the extension lowercase.

Answer (score -1):

You could do two things with your regex regarding the file-type extension.
You could add the all-caps extensions directly to the regex, i.e. `(tar|TAR)` or you can add the `?i` flag to make the search case-insensitive. See this for a guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43632/can-you-make-just-part-of-a-regex-case-insensitive

Then, regarding the multi-word completion, here is another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146098/properly-handling-spaces-and-quotes-in-bash-completion
(I personally use _ instead of spaces in all my files for this reason)

Comment: "you can add the ?i flag to make the search case-insensitive." --> Thanks for pointing me to that. I use a lot of regular expressions in other work I do and I'd never seen that before; however, it doesn't work for bash file globbing. Thanks for the link to the other answer... We'll see if I can get some inspiration from that.